# Counting and sorting multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| teacher | grade_1 | grade_2 | grade_3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Paul    |       1 | 0       | 3       |
| Mike    |       2 | 2       | 1       |
| Jens    |       3 | NULL    | 2       |
| Jens    |       2 | 3       | NULL    |
| Mike    |       1 | 2       | 1       |
| Paul    |       2 | 2       | 2       |
| Mike    |       1 | NULL    | NULL    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to produce an outcome like this:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| teacher | grade | count |
+---------+-------+-------+
| Jens    | NULL  |     2 |
| Jens    | 0     |     0 |
| Jens    | 1     |     0 |
| Jens    | 2     |     2 |
| Jens    | 3     |     2 |
| Mike    | NULL  |     2 |
| Mike    | 0     |     0 |
| Mike    | 1     |     4 |
| Mike    | 2     |     3 |
| Mike    | 3     |     0 |
| Paul    | NULL  |     0 |
| Paul    | 0     |     1 |
| Paul    | 1     |     1 |
| Paul    | 2     |     3 |
| Paul    | 3     |     1 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

So, every grade could have four different distinct values; NULL, 0, 1, 2 or 3
For every teacher, I would like to count the occurences of each grade in every grade column in total.

Is this possible? The actual table is much bigger with many more grade columns and more teachers.

My brain's totally stuck and I can't seem to think of a way to do it...

Best regards,
Jens

Comment: (Seriously) consider normalization

Comment: Look at `INNER FULL JOIN`s.